# Downloading a file via REST API

Tags: rest-api, api, files, contentversion

I need to download files with the API, using now

```
data/v59.0/sobjects/ContentVersion/{contentVersion}/VersionData
```

but

it's returning the entire file as application/octetstream but without a Content-Lenght header.
Is there a way to download it as multipart or get the header? Or maybe there is a better way to download.

Comment: What type of file and size of the file are you trying to download

Comment: Documents, pdfs, images. And the size can be any, really big ones too

Comment: related doc: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_blob_retrieve.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try getting the ContentSize when querying the ContentVersion, like this:

`SELECT ContentSize, VersionData FROM ContentVersion WHERE ContentDocumentId = '{id}' AND IsLatest = true`